# Yii package access the files in url

Tags: php, frameworks, yii2-user

I have installed YII2 of my local server and I also installed the a package.https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user now every thing is ready , I want to access this package in the url . My current URL is http://localhost/yii2-app-basic/web/index.php?r=site/about could any body help me in this regard.

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem , Actually I did not set the config problem. The YII2 basic version has different type of configuration e.g. you have to modify the console file and web file. in the config folder.